# JQuery + Prototype.js potential conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

the following code is being problematic.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<javascript/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {

// Start Tabbing <---------------------
// Hide features tab
$('#detailFeatures').hide();

$('#menu a').click(function(){

    if ($(this).attr('rel') == 'pdf') return true;

    selected = $(this).attr('href');

    // Clear active tab
    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');

    // Add class to clicked
    tab = selected + 'Tab';
    $(tab).addClass('active');

    // Hide all content
    $('.productTab').css('display','none');

    // Show selected tab
    $(selected).css('display','block');

    return false;

    });
// End Tabbing <------------------
```

The above code is used to create a tabbed panel that allows seeing either a product overview or a product feature list

In the console im getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ready'"

Im using the standard prototype.js for lightbox and jquery.js for the tabbing, unchanged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use two frameworks on one page :\

Comment: Well i'm not overly confident with JS, the page already had a tabbing method and i was just asked to implement a image gallery (lightbox-esque). Is there a jquery version of lightbox, or very similar?

Comment: It's not only javascript you are bad at : http://tinyurl.com/6x8x3g6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in an anonymous function:

```
(function($){
   //JQuery code here, example:
   $(document).ready(...);
})(jQuery);
```

This piece of code "converts" `$` "back" to a JQuery object, so that the code inside this wrapper can safely use JQuery methods on `$`.

Comment: Wrapped the whole thing in the function and it doesnt appear to help.

Comment: Because you've added `$.noConflict()` to your code.. Get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but is this the typical way to work with prototype?

Comment: @AlexGach It's just one of the ways.